# Python Vaex data type conversion: string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vaex

I'm utilizing the Vaex library in Python for a project; I'm still very new to Vaex so I apologize if this is elementary. I'm having an issue with a data type conversion. One of my columns 'Paid_at' has a datatype of str, and it should be a DateTime.
[df_paid.info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgHGN.png)

What I've done so far is dropped na from my df as well as (tried to) used pandas' to_datetime() to convert the column but it isn't working. This has worked in a pd data frame, but I am doing something wrong as I am receiving the following error

```
df_paid['Paid_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Paid_at'], errors='coerce')
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 df_paid['Paid_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Paid_at'], errors='coerce')
>
> F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py in **setitem**(self,
> name, value)    4431                 self.add_column(name, value)
> 4432             else:
> -> 4433                 self.add_virtual_column(name, value)    4434         else:    4435             raise TypeError('**setitem** only takes
> strings as arguments, not {}'.format(type(name)))
>
> F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py in
> add_virtual_column(self, name, expression, unique)    3249
> '# we rewrite all existing expressions (including the passed down expression argument)    3250             self._rename(name, renamed)
> -> 3251         expression = _ensure_string_from_expression(expression)    3252     3253         name = vaex.utils.find_valid_name(name, used=[] if not unique else
> self.get_column_names())
>
> F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\utils.py in
> _ensure_string_from_expression(expression)
> 764         return expression.expression
> 765     else:
> --> 766         raise ValueError('%r is not of string or Expression type, but %r' % (expression, type(expression)))
> 767
> 768
>
> ValueError: NaT is not of string or Expression type, but <class
> 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>

I'm a bit lost as to how I can get the Paid_at column to be a DateTime which I can aggregate from.

Answer (score 7):

```
df2['pdate']=df2.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

was solved here: https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/pull/440

Comment: what if datetime string like "202011091259"?