# What is Vaex function to parse string to datetime64, which equivalent to pandas to_datetime, that allow custom format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, vaex

I have date as string (example: 3/24/2020) that I would like to convert to `datetime64[ns]` format

```
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1["str_date"], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Use pandas `to_datetime` on vaex dataframe will result an error:

```
ValueError: time data 'str_date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

I have see maybe [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648122/python-vaex-data-type-conversion).

```
df2['pdate']=df2.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

However, the answer is type casting.  My case required to a format ('%m/%d/%Y') parse string to `datetime64[ns]`, not just type cast.

**Solution**: make custom function, then `.apply`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vaex` can use `apply` function for object operations, so you can use `datetime` and `np.datetime64` convert each date string, then apply it.

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

def convert_to_datetime(date_string):
    return np.datetime64(datetime.strptime(str(date_string), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))

df['date']  = df.date.apply(convert_to_datetime)
```

Comment: @ Joey Gao I tried using your solution on a similar problem where the string column has the format (%Y%m for example '201904') and it worked only when the column contains no blank cells. I was wondering how I could modify your code to solve my problem where there exist empty strings in the column. I'm also working with a Vaex dataset.

Comment: So, I figured out a way around this but still building on top @Joey Gao solution. To solve it, I simply did the following on the function he created:


def convert_to_datetime(date_string):
    for date in date_string:
        if date == '':
            np.nan
        else:
            return np.datetime64(datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m$d%H%M%S"))